# Need help regarding internationalization of iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have provided support for two languages, English and Chinese, in my iPhone application.  I use string files for the languages using "key"-"value" pairs and my application displays the appropriate language using `NSLocalizedString(@"Fund red not red?", @"")`.

I get only Chinese text when I run the app in XCode. How can I switch to different languages in XCode (iPhone simulator)?

Answer (score 2):

go to settings on the simulated iPhone and change the locale

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the answer, but I am new to iPhone, can u please tell me how to go to the settings and what are the changes to be made, because I am not getting any settings tab etc in the iPhone simulator on my Mac Book.

Comment: On the simulator, run your app, then quick by pressing the home button. Go to the first page (Swipe left to right normally) and there is the settings icon. Press General then International. Now you can change Language nad Region Format - same as on a real iPhone

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got how to change the language of the the IPhone app, but in my Application, i have used two xx.lproj files named en.lproj and zn-Hant.lproj(for chinese) with the respective *.strings files for translation with the "key" - "value" pairs. The text on my IPhone app(displayed using  the function "NSLocalizedString") is always coming in Chinese, even after changing the language of the Simulator. What is the procedure to make my Application to read different Serializable.strings (of different languages) based on the language selected for the IPhone simulator. Thanks in advance